# Word Form of Exclusive or

Tags: python, operators

I'm a little new to python, so I'm still learning things. I know you can do exclusive or by using `^`, but just out of curiosity, is there a way you can do an exclusive or in words? For example, you can use `and` instead of `&`, and you can do `or` instead of `||`. Is there one of those for `^`?

Comment: `and` and `&` are two very different operators, and so are `or` and `|` (there is no `||` in Python).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and` and `or` short-circuit, meaning if the left side makes the expression always `True` or always `False`, the right side won’t even be evaluated:

```
False and f()  # Doesn’t call f, because if one is False the result is always False
True or f()    # Doesn’t call f, because if one is True the result is always True

False & f()    # Calls f anyway
True | f()     # Calls f anyway
```

There’s no such short-circuiting left hand for exclusive-or (in `a ^ b`, no matter what `a` is, `b` could change the overall value), so there’s only a need for one operator.

To go into a bit more detail: `&`, `|`, and `^` are *overloadable* operators, meaning that types can define them to produce any value. (In the common case of `int`s, they act bitwise.) `and` and `or` aren’t, and always evaluate to one of their two operands: the left one if it’s falsy and the right one otherwise in the case of `and`, and the left one if it’s truthy and the right one otherwise in the case of `or`. For a hypothetical `xor` operator, it’s not clear which of these would be chosen.

```
>>> True and "hello"
"hello"
>>> 0 and True
0
>>> True or ""
True
>>> False or ""
""
>>> "truthy" xor "also truthy"
??? – can’t be either of these, because it has to be logically false
```

Comment: The main difference, of course, is that `and` and `or` operate on boolean values and `&` and `|` operate on individual bits.

Comment: @DYZ: `&` and `|` are overloadable to do anything, and they work as you’d expect on booleans, i.e. `True | False is True`.

Comment: `True | False is True` because `True` and `False` are represented as 1 and 0. But  `1 | 2` is 3 (and `3 is not True`).

Comment: @DYZ: `1` and `2` are also not booleans, and `1 and 2` is `2`.

Comment: But `1 & 2` is 0, which may come as a surprise to someone who forgets that `&` is applied bit-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `operator` module and note that when operating on two bools, xor is the same as checking inequality.

```
from operator import xor
bitwise_xor1 = a ^ b
bitwise_xor2 = xor(a,b)

from operator import ne
logical_xor1 = a != b
logical_xor2 = ne(a,b)
```

Note that for `bool`s, bitwise operation actually do return a `bool`, but for other types, they may not.

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't exist as of now but if you want support for macros you can use the [macro](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/macro/0.0.2) package from pypi.